# FTP Class not used

Tags: c#, ftp

today I tried C# for the first time. I want to upload a folder to an FTP Server and used this FTP CLass: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/443588/Simple-Csharp-FTP-Class

Now, when I use the Methods, it Says "Name ftpClient does not exist in that context". I will copy my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Net
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace DaloCloud
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static int x = 200;     // For Help-Screen
        static int y = 200;     // For Help-Screen
        string username;        // FTP-Username Value stored in there
        string password;        // FTP-Password Value stored in there
        string dirPath;         // C:\DaloUpload
        string uploadPath;       // ftp: //daloserver/users/username/files

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void helpButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create a new instance of Form2 and set its Visible property to true.
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            form2.Visible = true;

        }

        private void usernameTextbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            username = usernameTextbox.Text;
        }

        private void passwordTextbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            password = passwordTextbox.Text;
        }

        private void connectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dirPath, "*.*");
            string[] subDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(dirPath);

            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                ftpClient.upload(uploadPath + "/" + Path.GetFileName(file), file);
            }

            foreach (string subDir in subDirs)
            {
                ftpClient.createDirectory(uploadPath + "/" + Path.GetFileName(subDir));
                recursiveDirectory(subDir, uploadPath + "/" + Path.GetFileName(subDir));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So far I see, you never declared / initialized `ftpClient`.

Comment: Somewhere there ought to be something like `var ftpClient = new FTPClient()`

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your code.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you have to declare variables before you can use them. You haven't declared any variable named `ftpClient`.

This error is telling you quite concisely that `ftpClient` doesn't exist at the point you are using it. You must declare it to make it exist.

Might looks something like this:

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
```