# return statement in void methods

Tags: c#, return, void

so, I was recently searching for using a small library for FTP in C# ... I got through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782432/ftp-class-not-used) question to [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/443588/Simple-Csharp-FTP-Class) class....

I'm  wondering a bit about the sense of the `return` statement in all their void methods...

Here's for example their delete method:

```
     /* Delete File */
public void delete(string deleteFile)
{
    try
    {
        /* Create an FTP Request */
        ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(host + "/" + deleteFile);
        /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
        ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
        /* When in doubt, use these options */
        ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
        ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
        ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;
        /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
        ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
        /* Resource Cleanup */
        ftpResponse.Close();
        ftpRequest = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
    return;
}
```

My question is:

has the `return;` any reason or effect?

Comment: return is simply to end the function at that line. If the function had an actual type return, it would return a value if one is specified.

Comment: In general, this piece of code has questionable style that uses `try`/`catch` in every method, and catches all possible exceptions. I would not recommend using it as an example of coding style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the page every method ends with the pattern

```
catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
return /* Whatever the "default" return value would be on a error */;
```

Having a `return` as the last statement in a void method does not do anything to the program, my only guess is it is a pattern the poster of the article likes to follow. He had it on his other methods that returned a string...

```
catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
return "";
```

so he likely just wanted to keep the same pattern on the methods that returned void.

Answer (score 1):

No.

This can be used for early returns from the method, but this isn't the case here - `return;` at the end of a method is entirely redundant.

There is a perceptible difference in the generated IL code, *as long as you have optimizations disabled*, though. A void method with no `return` statement will simply contain a `ret` instruction, while adding a `return;` at the end will add a branch instruction - a jump to the `ret` instruction.

Answer (score 1):

No need to write meaningless explaination, the answer is simple: It doesn't have any sense

Answer (score 1):

It has no effect but I've seen it as well. I speculate (!) that some like to end their methods with `return` to have a larger visual indication on the end of the block than the closing bracket. It might also save you a split second if you change the return type at a later stage (from void to something else).

Answer (score 1):

There are *some issues* with your code:

1. In case of exception is thrown, `ftpReques`t will not be *closed* (resource leak)
2. Do you really want to *recreate* a class field (`ftpRequest`)?
3. Catching `Exception` smells
4. The last `return` is useless (your question)

The revisoned code could be something like that:

```
public void delete(string deleteFile) {
  try {
    // using over IDisposable is 
    using (var ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(host + "/" + deleteFile)) {
      ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
      // When in doubt, use these options 
      ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
      ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
      ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
      // Specify the Type of FTP Request 
      ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;
      // Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server 
      ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
    }
  }
  catch (WebException ex) {
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `return` statement at the end of a `void` method provides no additional effect. It can be removed without changing the semantics of the method.

One may use this `return` to simplify textual searching for the place from which the function returns, but it has no effect to the compiler.